Integrate an Okta app of type (regular web app) to ASP.Net zero web app (SPA)
I need to integrate an already existing Okta application of type regular web app to my ASP.Net zero app, the problem is okta configurations are meant for ASP.Net core MVC, is there any solution for this?
I tried to fit the configurations into my app but these configurations are using ASP.net core mvc SDK
